# What is the significance of the tangent equation $f(x) = A \tan\left(\frac{x+B}{C}\right) + D$?

Tags: trigonometry

I stumbled upon it myself while working with computer vision. Does anybody know any other references to this equation?

$$f(x) = A \tan\left(\frac{x+B}{C}\right) + D$$

Comment: If you rewrite $f(x) = A \tan\left(\frac{x+B}{C}\right) + D$ as $f(x) = A \tan\left(\frac{x}{C}+\frac{B}{C}\right) + D$ then there's some general thoughts here; https://www.coursehero.com/study-guides/precalctwo/graphs-of-the-other-trigonometric-functions/ plus there's the trig formula $tan(X+Y)=\frac{tan(X)+tan(Y)}{1-tan(X)tan(Y)}$